# In terms of sound, what are the advantages of a steel or nylon string?

Tags: guitar, strings, classical-guitar

I first picked up a guitar when I was about 7. Ever since I've been playing it, and I even performed a solo at a concert (Little Rover, by the stupendium!) I have 3 guitars, all acoustic. One hasn't been used in about a year and I'm thinking of selling it (any takers?) another is currently sidelined because of a broken string (not from my earlier question, that one has already been fixed) so I only have one that is in good enough shape to be played. The actual question here is for my guitar, it is currently strung with the top 3 strings brass and lower 3 nylon. I don't play professionally (yet) but I'm preparing a music festival in my town, and I want to know the advantages of both. Which one would produce a louder sound?

Comment: What make and model is the guitar in question?

Comment: Welcome! So it seems the answer to "can I change the strings on *this* guitar" is a simple "no." But if you want to ask "what are the pros/cons of nylon vs steel," then you're asking about two kinds of guitars. You could open a new question asking that. (You could also edit this question and have it re-opened, but in this case, when there's already answers and stuff, it's probably better to open a new one.) ...

Comment: ... Before doing so, please take a second to read about [the topics covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [how to avoid subjective answers](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). For instance, "which is better, classical or steel-string" wouldn't be a good question, but "what makes a classical guitar better suited to classical/folk/flamenco music" might be.

Comment: Good revision. Very clear now why the other linked posts didn't provide the answer.

Comment: @Aaron Huh. I still don’t get it. Still seems like a question about whether to put steel strings on a classical guitar or not. And we still don’t have the make and model of the guitar in question. I myself can’t see why this was reopened. It seems hardly different at all.

Comment: @ToddWilcox As it stands, the last two sentences are the real question, and the rest is incidental (/distracting/confusing) personal info.

Comment: @AndyBonner But the last sentence still doesn't make sense or is answered by one of the dupes that used to be linked here. The advantage of nylon strings is they can be used on nylon string guitars. The advantage of steel strings is they can be used on steel string guitars. A string is not louder than another string - all strings by themselves are extremely quiet when vibrating. Different guitars, on the other hand, are capable of different dynamic ranges. Is the question actually about nylon string **guitars** vs steel string **guitars**?

Comment: @ToddWilcox yup, I think that's the current intent. I mean, if I'm gonna play flamenco or Albeniz or Joni Mitchell, I want a nylon-string guitar, and if I'm gonna play Greenday-unplugged I want steel—but why? which *is* louder, and what are other differences? I'm not actually sure enough myself to offer an answer. I could tell you about the differences between gut-string-baroque violin and "modern" violin, which are probably pretty similar...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither steel nor nylon strings on their own produce very much sound at all, even when stretched and plucked. A vibrating string of any material just doesn't couple with enough air for the sound of it to be clearly audible.

That is why guitars have large, hollow, wooden bodies. The body of a guitar couples the energy of the vibrating string to a larger amount of air, acting as an amplifier for the string. The things that make a guitar sound louder or quieter are the construction of the bridge, top, back, and sides. There are also resonator guitars that have special designs intended to get more volume out of a guitar without making it much larger.

So the answer to which **string** is louder is neither. They are both extremely quiet on their own.

If you are curious about which kind of guitar is louder, then guitars that can be strung with steel strings are capable of more volume than guitars that must be strung with nylon strings.

In terms of "advantages" and "disadvantages" of nylon versus steel strings, it doesn't really work like that. You (almost) never have a choice between whether to put nylon or steel strings on the same guitar. Nylon string guitars must use nylon strings; steel string guitars must use steel strings.

On a nylon string guitar:

- The advantage of nylon strings is you can put them on the guitar and the guitar will sound and play correctly.
- The disadvantage of steel strings is if you try to put them on, it will be difficult and you run the risk of damaging the guitar.

On a steel string guitar:

- The advantage of steel strings is they will fit and work as intended and the guitar will sound and play correctly.
- The disadvantage of nylon strings is they will be very hard to put on and the guitar won't sound or play correctly at all. At least in this case there is no chance of damage to the guitar.

Comment: I've been keeping quiet about it since I don't know, but is the tension of the two very different? I imagine that plays a role in volume?

Comment: @AndyBonner yes, typically nylon strings have half the tension of steel strings

Comment: @ToddWilcox in my entire life I've only seen one guitar where it was interchangeable.

Comment: @AndyBonner I don’t think tension and volume are strongly correlated. I think there is a link but it’s not linear. I’d look at mass per unit length as more connected with possible volume. At the same frequency and maximum displacement, a more massive (denser) string will have more momentum, which correlates with more energy transfer to the top.

Comment: I guess, for a given pitch, if you increase the tension and keep the vibrating length the same, you can decrease the mass... which... makes it *softer*? Changes the timbre, ie overtone blend, anyway; big fat ropy gut bass strings have that "muddy" sound...

Comment: Denser string needs higher tension if length and pitch are kept constant. And yes, thicker strings tend to dampen higher overtones.

Comment: @AndyBonner I personally have no idea what a "big fat ropy gut bass string" sounds like. I'm not sure how much timbre is affected by thickness. I think the modulus of elasticity and other factors may be more important. I do know for certain that thick nylon classical guitar strings can be played **very** brightly with the correct technique. For both steel and nylon strings, the available brightness does decrease for a given string as the tension is reduced. But the number of available tone colors is not significantly different between steel and nylon string guitars.

Comment: Have to disagree with some points here. On at least a couple of my classical guitars, it would be very easy to fit steel strings. Depends on the bridge configuration. Not that I'd want to do that. Nylon strings on a steel-strung guitar, yes, awkward to fit, usually. Volume? Maybe something to do with classical guitars are usually played with fingers (O.k. nails as well), whereas others will almost inevitably use a plectrum, which could well sound louder.

Answer (score 5):

The answer to your question is `Yes`, you should keep it like that else you risk damaging your guitar. As others stated, the three brass strings are nylon cores wound in brass (or other metal). If you buy a pack of "nylon" strings you will likely find the same configuration. It is standard.

On the off chance that someone put nylon on an acoustic guitar, then you would be fine to try out metal acoustic guitar strings. I HIGHLY doubt that this is the case, it sounds like your guitar is a "classical" guitar.

Comment: This doesn’t address the question of advantages one way or the other.

Comment: @Awalrod Just inspected the guitar thoroughly, it's a yamaha, and it says "classical" on the soundbox label.

Comment: @TheWantedOne You said the linked answers do not answer your question but they do. The first answer in the first link says this: “**You should only use nylon strings on this guitar.**” That’s your answer. You don’t have an option to put steel strings on it. Nylon only.

Comment: @ToddWilcox if you read the entire question (I know, doing so instead of going for knee jerk reaction might get you downvoted) it's really about whether the OP should replace the strings on classical guitar with new nylon strings.

Comment: @ojs I’ve read all of the content of all three questions (this and the two linked ones), including all answers and comments. Your mention of getting downvoted makes no sense because I’ve only voted to close and commented and neither action can be downvoted. I’m not sure which question you are saying is about replacing strings (since there are three questions under discussion - or have you not read all if the content?) but it doesn’t matter. The asker has a classical guitar. The asker should only use nylon strings on their classical guitar. That is their answer. No more is needed.

Comment: @ToddWilcox the questions main issue was advantage/disadvantage. but seeing that this question was closed because everyone is so quick to closevote, I'm not going to get my answer. Only one person said something even remotely close to what I was asking.

Comment: @TheWantedOne Maybe we’re confused by your question. You can’t choose between nylon or steel strings to put on a guitar. You must put nylon strings on guitars made for nylon strings and steel strings on guitars made for steel strings. The advantage of nylon strings is they are the only strings you can use for a nylon string guitar. The advantage of steel strings is they are the only strings you can use for a steel string guitar. You wrote in your question, "should I keep it like this?" And the answer to that is **yes, you must keep it like that**. That is exactly what you asked.

Comment: @ToddWilcox sorry, I was intending to reply to Aaron and missed that autocomplete had filled in someone different. My mistake, and unfortunately ironic one.

Answer (score 0):

There is a huge difference in Young's modulus between nylon and steel, see:
[What is "Young's modulus", and how does it relate to guitar?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/114472/what-is-youngs-modulus-and-how-does-it-relate-to-guitar)

Nylon strings change pitch less than steel when bent, either voluntarily or involuntarily, so they provide more stable intonation.

Nylon strings sound inherently more mellow, as they produce less high harmonics.

That being said, it's not really a choice whether to put steel or nylon strings on a guitar. As the others said, you need an appropriately made instrument to benefit from the string qualities. **Moreover, putting steel strings on a classical guitar may damage the instrument due to increased tension.**

Comment: "Nylon strings change pitch less than steel when bent, either voluntarily or involuntarily, so they provide more stable intonation." —but, in my experience, they stretch more during the "break-in" period, right?

Comment: @AndyBonner true, in general they may not hold tuning as well as steel strings over longer periods.

Comment: @ToddWilcox _The science of string instruments_ T.Rossing, chapter 8.2.2, attributes it to softness of the material and internal absorption of high frequencies, in nylon and gut strings, as opposed to metal strings.